# Running vim sometimes causes vnc server to crash

Tags: ubuntu, vim, crash, vnc, tightvnc

I use tightvnc on Ubuntu 14.04.1.  Sometimes, when I run vim, the vnc server dies.  I see the following messages in my VNC log:

> Window manager warning: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on display ':1'.
> xterm: fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) or KillClient on X server ":1"
>
> (gnome-panel:12289): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-panel: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
>
> g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.

The vnc server process is always gone after this happens.

/usr/share/bug/xserver-xorg-core/script 3>&1 doesn't reveal anything useful; I suspect it's for Xvnc and not Xtightvnc.

.xsession-errors is always empty after the failure.

The failure happens right when vim starts, but only occasionally (less than 1% of the time.)

I'm actually starting vim using "vi" (old habits die hard!) but I doubt that's significant.  I disabled the vim feature to set the window title, but that had no effect.  Any ideas about figuring out what's going on?  (Meanwhile I'm substituting Xvnc for Xtightvnc, no idea what the differences are, if any.)

Not sure it's significant, but I always have two vnc sessions open, one for each screen on my Windows laptop.

I don't have root access on the Ubuntu machine (arrgh), but I can file a case  if necessary.  /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern is "|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P" and apport isn't enabled.

Comment: ... crickets ...

I substituted Xvnc instead of Xtightvnc and haven't seen the issue yet ... fingers crossed.

Comment: So much for crossed fingers.  I need a better magic spell.  Xvnc worked great for a long time, but the problem is now happening .. happened twice today.  Any help debugging this without root access would be highly appreciated!

Comment: PS: it also happens when I start xterms.

Comment: I subsequently found out that the issue was specifically the number of open windows.  When the number exceeded some limit, vnc crashed.  IIRC the number was around 30.  Closing unnecessary windows helped to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known bug:

https://technotes.tt4living.com/debian/tightvnc-1-3-9-server-crashes-with-xtightvnc1077-segfault

Good news: an update should fix it.