# TightVNC server crashes when scrolling in gedit in XFCE

Tags: debian, vnc, vncserver, tightvnc, vnc-viewer

I'm using TightVNC Server version 1.3.9 on a Debian Buster VM, and TightVNC Viewer version 2.8.11 on Windows 10 1709.

If I

1. Run the VNC Server using `vncserver -geometry 1920x1080` and the `xstartup` given below:

```
xrdb $HOME/.Xresource
autocutsel -fork
startxfce4 # xfce-session
```

2. Connect using the following settings:

[image]

3. Open `gedit` and start writing a file that's long enough to cause a scrollbar to appear.
4. Start scrolling.

Then I can consistently crash the VNC server. I'm sure there's no magical bug in gedit causing it, but I've found this to be the simplest way to reproduce the issue.

The log output is as follows:

`~/.vnc/name:display.log`:

```
xfce4-appfinder: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
wrapper-1.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
Gdk-Message: 11:03:46.612: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.

wrapper-1.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
Gdk-Message: 11:03:46.612: evolution-alarm-notify: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.

xfsettingsd: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
xfwm4: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
xfce4-panel: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
Gdk-Message: 11:03:46.615: Thunar: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

xfce4-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
xfdesktop: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
```

`/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jan 31 11:03:46 hostname kernel: [156856.632633] Xtightvnc[67799]: segfault at 7ffc9df4e9b8 ip 000055e039b8e158 sp 00007ffc9df4e9c0 error 6 in Xtightvnc[55e039a42000+184000]
Jan 31 11:03:46 hostname kernel: [156856.632645] Code: 41 0f bf 74 24 08 48 83 e0 f0 45 0f b7 44 24 0e 41 b9 02 00 00 00 48 29 c4 49 8b 45 18 4c 89 5d 98 4c 8d 54 24 0f 49 83 e2 f0 <41> 52 4c 89 55 a0 57 4c 89 ef 45 31 ed ff 90 00 01 00 00 41 8b 7c
```

The server leaves behind its lock files in `/tmp/.X1-lock` and `/tmp/.X11-unix/X1` which will then have to be deleted manually.

What could be the cause of this and how would I remedy this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the same error that affected [this Gnome user](https://superuser.com/q/1220907/882325) and [this KDE user](https://technotes.tt4living.com/debian/tightvnc-1-3-9-server-crashes-with-xtightvnc1077-segfault).

The latter proposes building TightVNC 1.3.10 from source instead. With instructions on how to do so on Debian are very limited, one either has to fight GCC build errors for an eternity, or just do what they suggest: Replace TightVNC with TigerVNC; the user interface is the same, and it's possible to use TightVNC Viewer with the TigerVNC server; replacing the server amounts to running

```
sudo apt purge tightvncserver
sudo apt install vnc4server
```

With that, `vncserver` is available just as it would be with TightVNC.